# datagridview changes do not reflect in dataset ties to

Tags: c#

I have a windows form that has my datagridview object in it and I use the following code to set the datasource of this dgv object:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notesDataSet = notesClient.GetPatientNotes("6236321.00");

    dataGridView1.DataSource = notesDataSet.Tables[0];
}
```

notesClient.GetPatientNotes()n does the retrieving of the data and returns the correct dataset. As a matter of
fact I acutally see the data in my dgv. The problem is that after change values in my dgv and use the following code in my save button:

```
notesDataSet.AcceptChanges();
if (notesDataSet.HasChanges())
   {
       DataSet editDataSet = notesDataSet.GetChanges();
       notesClient.UpdatePatientNotes(editDataSet);
   }
```

the if block does not even get executed like there were no changes to the dataset at all. Now I know that there 
were no changes directly to the dataset but isn't the whole purpose of binding dgv with the datasource is that
any changes to dgv will be reflected in the dataset, what am I missing that my changes are not being transfered
to my dataset. I am new to c# and using my prior programming exp I assumed that binding dgv with the datasource
will show changes in dgv to dataset and vice versa? am I incorrect in assuming that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense that your code block is not executing because it always will evaluate to `False` when called directly after `AcceptChanges`.

`AcceptChanges()` changes any `DataRow`'s `RowState` from `Added` or `Modified` to `UnChanged`, or `Deleted` to `Removed`.

Therefore when you evaluate `HasChanges()`, it will return false in this case.

If you want to perform action on the rows that contain changes, you will want to call those methods before you call `AcceptChanges()`.

Edit:

Brief example of what I think your code should look like to perform correctly:

```
    if (notesDataSet.HasChanges())
    {
        DataSet editDataSet = notesDataSet.GetChanges();
        notesClient.UpdatePatientNotes(editDataSet);
    }
    notesDataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

This way you are still calling your `UpdatePatientNotes` method and have the `editDataSet` showing any changes in your dataset.  And then after you execute the `if` block, you `AcceptChanges()`.

Hope that helps somehow.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, moving acceptchanges() after processing the changes is exactly what was needed and now my code works as I desired. The only reason I put acceptchanges() before my code was that because of my background in other languages I have worked with I thought that acceptchanges() will simply commit the changes to the dgv but now after your suggested changes I also realized that i was calling acceptchanges() on the dataset and not on dgv and it would make sense to process the changes first and then call acceptchanges(). In any case thanks to your reply.

Comment: on a side note I was not able to reply to Evan's reply (it could be because of my low points)

Comment: I also wanted to flag Evan's reply as 'answer' to my question but I am not able to do that as well. if someone who has the permission can mark it as 'answer' I would appreciate ;

Comment: You should be able to click the Green check mark underneath the upvote/downvote buttons.  I'm glad this worked for you!

Comment: OK the green check mark did work and thanks for ur reply and ur answer